# Meals orders or meals order or meal orders

Tags: grammar

I came across the explanation of noun adjunct but still unsure which is the correct one to use in the example below. I'm unsure if the *order* here is considered as a noun or a verb.

Example sentence and its variation:

1. For *meals order*,  please pre-order at least 1 week in advance.
2. For *meals orders*,  please pre-order at least 1 week in advance.
3. For *meal orders*,  please pre-order at least 1 week in advance.
4. For *meal order*,  please pre-order at least 1 week in advance.

I'm also thinking if the prefix *pre* in *pre-order* is unnecessary if the sentence has stated *1 week in advance*.

Comment: *Orders* doesn't seem like it could be a verb here.  For one thing, it looks like a conjugated verb -  he/she/it *orders* - but that doesn't make sense: where is the subject?

Comment: Hi @stangdon, from my limited command of English grammar, not a native speaker, I personally see "Meals" as the noun/subject here.

Answer (score 1):

A "noun adjunct" is when a word that's normally only a noun acts like a modifier - specifically, an adjective.

Some languages want adjectives to be plural to agree with nouns that are plural.  Not English.

So - *meal orders.*

*Possessive nouns* end in *'s* or *s'* - and I guess those are noun adjuncts as well.  I bring that up to say that *meals orders* will sound like you are saying *meal's orders* - meaning orders that belong to a meal.  And it's not incorrect to say that, and the meaning won't really be too different than *meal orders*.

---

> I'm unsure if the order here is considered as a noun or a verb.

Verbs (not verbals) appear after subject pronouns, unless they are commands.  And you'll never have a command with a preposition in front of it.

---

> I'm also thinking if the prefix pre in pre-order is unnecessary if the sentence has stated 1 week in advance.

Technically not needed, but it's OK to be redundant to add clairity.  Especially when providing guidelines to the public or a large audience, this gives people not paying full attention additional chances to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It should be "For meal orders"

The word "order" is a count noun and it can be made plural. "Meals orders" sounds odd for the same reason that "the animals kingdom" sounds odd. It should be "the animal kingdom".

I also searched the Internet and you get plenty of results for "meal orders".